# Trouble binding a data class that has numerous String, Bool and Array properties. Using Xcode 9.4.1 with Swift 4.2 for macOS

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I am trying to create a macOS project using Xcode 9.4.1 with Swift 4.2.  I am using a Document-Based Application since I am entering data.  The project has a class that includes an array as a property along with other properties.  This class will be used to enter data that will need to persist and I'm trying to use IB and bindings to get this to work.

Here is the class (The actual class has much more String, Bool and Array properties):

```
class MyClass: NSObject {

    @objc dynamic var property1 = ""
    @objc dynamic var property2 = true
    @objc dynamic var property3 = true

    @objc dynamic var myClass2s: [myClass2] = []
}


class myClass2: NSObject {
    @objc dynamic var property4 = ""
    @objc dynamic var property5 = ""
}
```

I can get a tableView with an arrayController to work for the String and Bool properties.  The difficulty for me comes in when I need to have another tableView for the MyClass2 data to be entered, which requires another arrayController.  I can't seem to figure out how to bind it all together.

**EDIT 9/30**

I've tried binding the details tableView's Table Content to MyClassArrayController, Controller Key: selection, Model Key Path: myClass2s.  I have a second Array Controller for MyClass2 so I can add/remove data to MyClass2.  When I run the project, I don't get any errors, however, I can't add data to MyClass2 objects with its table View content bound to the array myClass2s.

So, in addition to what I tried above, I bound MyClass2ArrayController's Content Array to MyClassArrayController, selection, myClass2s and so far it appears to be working now.

Comment: I'd suggest you look for a "master-details" example. There are lots of samples out there, but the basic idea is that you have one table (the master table) that displays a collection of MyClass objects bound to properties (`property1`, ...). When you select one of these, a second view (the details) is displayed. The source for the details view is the selection in the master table. You bind the details view(s) to the `arrayController.selection` of a the master array controller. For example, a second list view bound to `arrayControler.selection.myClass2s` would display the list of sub-objects.

Comment: I'm trying to work through this.  I'm still having trouble figuring out how to do the Master-Detail for a one-to-many relationship.

Comment: I can't find an example of having the master as a tableView and the details also as a tableView.  I've tried binding a text field of myClass2's tableView to myClass' ArrayController with the controller key set to selection.  I'm having trouble with the Model Key Path since it is a different class. I think I'll need a separate array controller for myClass2 with associated enter and delete buttons, but then I'm back to trying to figure out how to make one array controller the master and the other array controller the details.

Comment: I think I worked it out.  Thanks James.  See edit in main question.

Comment: I'm not exactly following the details, but it sounds like you're on the right track.